# How to output an integer value in command line argument to characters of the equivalent length as the value in C++?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I got a value say 10 and i want to output this into xxxxxxxxxx (10 x). How do i do this?
The value 10 is passed in via the command line.

I have tried this, but it doesn't do what I want:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){                 
    cout << argv[i++] << " " << argv[i] << endl;
} // i cant get the argv[i] to print out the value in 'x'
```

Comment: There is no `x` in your code, so where is it coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (argc>1)
  cout << string(atoi(argv[1]), 'x');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way using the streams, but I don't know it offhand:  it's something like cout.SetPrecision().  But the C way is to provide a format specification.

```
int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf ("%*d\n", atoi(argv[1]), 10);  // outputs 10 into fieldwidth given by parameter
}
```

This needs quite a bit of development to handle pathologies of input, but the basic concept works.  `*` means use the next parameter as a field width.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need

```
std::cout << std::string(10, 'x');
```

So fullblown:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, const char* args[])
{
    if (argc>1)
    {
        std::istringstream iss(args[1]);
        unsigned long i = 0;
        iss >> i;
        std::cout << std::string(i, 'x');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See [here](http://codepad.org/k0sREqAM)